Girl ghost who kills guy driving
I really want to find the name of this scary movie I saw when I was younger.

There was this ghost woman/girl who wore all white
This young guy was driving in a highway at the night and crashed into the ghost
When he got out to see who it was, he didn't see anything
The next day the police found his body dead (I believe his body was chopped in different parts, I don't remember.)
looks around 2006 or 2007 idk

Can someone please help me find the name of the movie?

You remember language/country of the movie?

Um it was english and from the The united states i think

It sounds a lot like the pilot episode of Supernatural. Not a movie though.

There was this ghost woman/girl who wore all white - check
This young guy was driving in a highway at the night and crashed into the ghost - he was driving, saw the ghost and slammed on the brakes - he either went through her or she disappeared
When he got out to see who it was, he didn't see anything - check
The next day the police found his body dead (I believe his body was chopped in
different parts, I don't remember.) - honestly can't remember if this was exactly the case but there was definitely at least one death
looks around 2006 or 2007 idk - aired 2005


please add some detail about why you think this matches...

have added some more detail.

I believe you are referencing the pilot episode of the TV series Supernatural. It features a "woman in white" theme. She found her husband being unfaithful, killed her kids, then jumped off a bridge. She then starts killing (I think) men who have sinful thoughts or actions. That's why Dean becomes a target. She can't "go home" because the ghosts of her children are there.

There's already an answer that suggests the same thing.
